# boxshadow to match design

Tags: css

I got this design:

http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/1363/desginer.jpg

I'm trying to get the best result using:

```
        div.image {
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #bbb;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #bbb;
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #bbb;
            padding: 2px;
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
        }

<div class="image"><img width="120" height="120" src="image.jpg" title="title" alt="alt" /></div>
```

But I tried a lot of values and I'm still not sure what's the best one. Any tips?

Comment: I don't know why I got downvoted on this one. =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

From the page:

> **The Syntax:**
>   box-shadow: none | < shadow > [ , < shadow > ]*
>   < shadow > = inset? && [ < length >{2,4} && < color >? ]

So, the first values can be the `X`(left) and `Y`(top) position, the third is the blur spred and the fouth is the color.

You can also specify `inset` at the start to create a inner shadow.

In your case, you will have to zero the top and left offset and define a blur radius accordingly:

```
div.image {
    ...
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #bbb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #bbb;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #bbb;
}
```

Comment: I got my code using the same url. The example F uses 4 values. I'm goona read it later more carefully. But thx, I will use your code.

Comment: If so, see the E example and tweek the third parameter.

Answer (score 1):

this does what you want; no 3rd value, a bit more on the 4th http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/LAT5B/

Comment: why do you use all this? `-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #bbb;` `-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #bbb;` `-o-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #bbb;` `-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #bbb;` `box-shadow: 0 0 4px #bbb;`?

Comment: cross-browser compatibility. -ms (ie) -moz (ff) -o (opera) -webkit (chrome, safari)

Comment: is the backup...they all work together to make sure if the browser supports box-shadow, then it shows. box-shadow is the default backup.

Comment: I think -ms is obsolete, since IE 9 supports the standard.

Comment: lame. i gave you the same answer...first. lame.

Comment: @rcdmk true that. i think it helps on ie mobile, but i'd have to look into it. i just use them all out of habit

Comment: It's OK. Theres nothing to harm.

Answer (score 1):

For me, with that the perfect values :
http://jsfiddle.net/D2LVq/1/

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can get a shadow to your sample is this: `0 0 8px #666`